# How to connect to Snowflake Web UI with custom OAuth integration

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Hi I created an external custom OAuth security integration like so :

```
create or replace security integration fred_oauth_integration
    type = external_oauth
    enabled = true
    external_oauth_type = custom
    external_oauth_issuer = 'http://$(some_endpoint)/snowflakeAuth/accessToken'
    external_oauth_jws_keys_url = 'https://$(some_endpoint)/snowflakeAuth/jsonWebKeySet'
    external_oauth_audience_list = ('https://xxxx.us-east-1.snowflakecomputing.com')
    external_oauth_scope_mapping_attribute = 'scp'
    external_oauth_token_user_mapping_claim='upn'
    external_oauth_snowflake_user_mapping_attribute='login_name';
```

How to get redirected to my identity provider when I want to use the Snowflake Web UI (https://xxxx.us-east-1.snowflakecomputing.com/console/login#/)?

Is there a specific URL or some configuration to enable that ?

Comment: There is for SSO, explained [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/admin-security-fed-auth-overview.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the OAuth part is for Web UI login mechanism.It is more of a connection mechanism between applications like Power BI, Tableau etc and using command line mechanism.
For being able to use authentication mechanism for UI, leverage Single Sign On feature available for Snowflake.